# Angular2 component: impossible to emit an @Output EventEmitter inside ngOnDestroy?

Tags: angular

[angular2 rc1]

Is it possible to have a component like this:

```
export class MyComp {
  @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter(false)

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myEvent.emit('ngOnDestroy hook');
  }
}
```

And catch it in the parent:

`<myComp (myEvent)="test($event)"></myComp>`

It seems to be impossible but I would like to understand why?

I know I can use a service to walk through.

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/hSg162?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 ngOnDestroy, emit event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743069/angular2-ngondestroy-emit-event)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A service is a good solution, but you wanted to understand why:

## A TL/DR explanation:

The subscription is unsubscribed for you, by angular **before** ngOnDestroy() is called. This automation happens because your subscribed on a template, angular parses the template and knows enough to do so.

## A more detailed explanation:

Angular generates a factory for each component, this process is called Code generation and the factory function created by angular returns an instance of a unique **View** type created according to the metadata of your component, which inherits the **AppView** class.

The whole lifecycle of a component instance is managed by the view. For example,  change detection and of course lifecycle hooks.

Before the **ngOnDestroy** lifecycle hook is called (by the internal view of your component) an internal destruction function is called, it does some cleaning for you.
One of cleaning operations is unsubscribing from all events such as click, mouse move and **custom events** which are @Output emitters defined in child components.

This is done statically, which means that the code generator knows about the event subscription and so it adds **hardcoded** logic to remove it.
Its an important thing, this saves a lot of boilerplate code and prevent memory leaks - the framework cleans up for you.

It's also important to note that angular can do it because it has a lot of metadata about what's going on.
It knows that its a subscriptions because it parses the **Template** and find an event expression (e.g: `(click)="something()"`) and also because of the **@Output** decorator in **MyComp**

You can see the logic quite clearly in the **AppView** class - [LINK](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/linker/view.ts#L195-L201)
Every view inherits from **AppView** and implements (among other things) a function called **destroyInternal**.
The order is that on destruction **destroyLocal()** is called (defined on AppView), destroyLocal will clean up all subscriptions and disposable items and then it will call **destroyInternal**, **destroyInternal** will then call **ngOnDestroy()** on your component's instance.

## A Solution:

Now, services might be a good solution but if you understand what's going on you can solve this without the help of an external service, it very simple.
As we now know, angular will unsubscribe from subscriptions registered in a template, if we register manually (i.e: using code) we will be able to fire the events.

While simple, it has some boilerplate since we need to:

- We need to get a reference to our child component, we will use ViewChild
- We need to subscribe to the event on our child component instance but we can do it **only** after the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is fired.
- We need to unsubscribe once we're done, this can be done in several ways, the best way is to **complete** the EventEmitter - we will do it in the component that defines the EventEmitter simply by call `myEvent.complete()`. It will dispose everything for us.

Here is the destroy function:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.myEvent.emit('ngOnDestroy hook');
  this.myEvent.complete();
}
```

And here is the MyApp component:

```
export class MyApp {
  displayComp = true

  @ViewChild('mycomp', {read: MyComp}) myComp: MyComp;
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myComp.myEvent.subscribe( () => alert('myApp > receive event via MANUAL Subscription'));
  }

  test(e) {
    alert('myApp > receive event');
  }
}
```

Here is a working plunker - [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/7jXGGE?p=preview)

UPDATE: I just noticed a [pending PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9946) for this issue in the angular repo, it's 12 days now still not merged, it takes time to merge community contribution so lets hope it will land in the next RC.

Answer (score 3):

This PR should fix this problem. It changes the behavior that `ngOnDestroy()` is called before the events are detached.

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9946