# no-unused-variable TSLint rule does not work with private @HostBinding

Tags: angular, angular6, encapsulation, tslint, angular2-hostbinding

In my TSLint file, I have:

```
"no-unused-variable": true
```

In my components, I sometimes have:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-variable
@HostBinding('class') private classes = 'my-theme';
```

Because `classes` is private, TSLint complains, so I have to disable TSLint everytime.

I **do not** want to make `@HostBinding` public because of encapsulation.

What is the recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it a bug that it thinks it is unused?  If you are only using it in the constructor you don’t need the word `private`.  I think tslint will complain when you’re making something an instance variable and only using it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the solution is to simply make it `public`

```
@HostBinding('class') public classes = 'my-theme';
```

This is because from Angular's perspective, it accesses the component, something like `component.classes`. Therefore, semantically, it is public. It's the same reason why `@Input` should be public even if you don't use it in the template.

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469573/3481582

Answer (score 5):

You have two options, as far as I know.

1 - Use `protected`. Self explaining:

```js
@HostBinding('class') protected classes = 'my-theme';
```

2 - Use `ignore-pattern`. The variable and import names matching the specified pattern will be ignored by this rule according to [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/). The pattern is a regex and `^_` means any string starting with `_`.

tslint.json:

```
...
"no-unused-variable": [true, {"ignore-pattern": "^_"}]
...
```

component:

```js
@HostBinding('class') private _classes = 'my-theme';
```

**Bonus**

If your variable is readonly, you can do one of these too. It will not prevent the tslint error but it will prevent modifying the variable accidentally if that is what worries you about encapsulation.

```js
@HostBinding('class') private readonly classes = 'my-theme';
@HostBinding('class') private get classes() { return 'my-theme'; }
```